# Can I auto-generate subtitles from a video file?

Tags: video, subtitles

Is there software that can generate subtitles based on the speech from the a video file (e.g. WMV, MPEG, etc)?

Comment: How? You mean, generating text from the speech of a video file?

Comment: @slhck, something like that or similar. I believe that that is the only way to generate the subtitle for those video that do not have hardcode subtitle or subtitle file.

Comment: … well, or you could write them yourself. Haven't heard of a program that does this all in one step. Don't forget that this won't work reliably (see for example YouTube's auto close-captioning).

Comment: @slhck, yes, google also have one (reference: http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2360955,00.asp#fbid=O92izD-Xp-K) but I believe one day some company or research center will come one out.

Comment: Use iPhones siri.. just make sure its not Irish accent

Comment: You could try running the video through a speech-recognition program and then tweaking the timings (and text) with a subtitle program. That may be the "quickest" and/or "easiest" and/or most accurate and/or cheapest method. Like they say, pick two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried that Youtube one and it's terrible - It can't deal with American accents let alone UK ones which I need.

The best solution I've found is http://speakertext.com/ they provide a captioning service for 
$2 per minute of video.

Comment: I will be on a lookout for software / website that can perform at a affordable and quality conversion.