# How to generate subtitle from text and video

Tags: subtitles

I have seen [this](https://superuser.com/questions/342374/can-i-auto-generate-subtitles-from-a-video-file) question but my one is a little different.

I have the video of some lectures and also the exact text of the lectures. The lectures are in US English. The audio is good, no audible noise, no background music. I can separate the audio from video if necessarily.

So, is there any tool with which I can generate the subtitles? Linux solutions are good for me but windows will be OK too.

Comment: How is yours different?

Comment: @Synetech Looks like it's different because he actually has the text and needs to make a subtitle file.

Comment: But is the text that of what is being said or just notes? If it is what is actually being said (peculiar) then where did it come from and why is it not already a subtitle (like I said, it would be peculiar for them to specifically provide subs, but as a separate file). @Mohaimin, you could just use a [subtitle editor](https://www.google.com/search?q=subtitle+editor).

Comment: @Synetech: The text is exactly the same as the speech in the video. The text and the video is from different source.

Comment: That's really strange. Where did you get a copy of the subtitles to your lectures? (Oh wait, I am assuming that this is a school thing; is it like an online tutorial instead? That would make sense.) In any case, just use one of the subtitle editors that I liked to. (Technically asking for software recommendations is apparently now frowned upon, but you can certainly [Google for subtitle editor reviews](https://www.google.com/search?q=subtitle+editor+reviews).)

Comment: What format is the text? Does it have time-codes or just plain-text?

Comment: @Synetech: Its not a school thing. I got some DVD of the lectures from a friend. And I got lecture texts online. The text is plain text (HTML actually).

Comment: Do the rendered HTML files (e.g., when viewed in a browser) have time-codes or formatting or is it just plain text?

Comment: Plain text. Its not problem if it was not plain text. We could extract plain text from HTML. No time code. Plain and simple text. In fact, no paragraph or line breaks are there.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search found that there is a tool called Subtitle editor (http://home.gna.org/subtitleeditor/) in most distribution repositories which would allow you to make external subtitle files that can be used with a wide range of video players.